# Why datamapper methods doesn't work?

Tags: ruby, datamapper

I tried to access to my existing data thanks to Datamapper.
But it doesn't work. All the methods like `.first`, `.all`,... return nothing. `.update` return an `undefined method update for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)`...

I'm sure the database is not empty because this code return well the `new_consultation.date`

```
new_consultation = Consultation.new
new_consultation.name = name_prestation
new_consultation.expense = expense_prestation
new_consultation.date = date_prestation.empty? ? Time.now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y") : date_prestation 
new_consultation.save
puts new_consultation
puts new_consultation.date
```

This is the whole code :

```
DataMapper.setup(:default, 'sqlite:medical_expenses.db')
class Consultation
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id, Serial
  property :name, Text, required: true
  property :expense, Text, required: true
  property :date, Text, required: true
  property :refund, Text, required: true 
end
DataMapper.finalize()
DataMapper.auto_upgrade!()

# Enter and save new consultation
puts 'Prestations ?'
name_prestation = gets.chomp
puts 'Montant ?' 
expense_prestation = gets.chomp
puts 'Date ? (par défaut date du jour)'
date_prestation = gets.chomp
print "Dépense enregistrée"

new_consultation = Consultation.new
new_consultation.name = name_prestation
new_consultation.expense = expense_prestation
new_consultation.date = date_prestation.empty? ? Time.now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y") : date_prestation 
new_consultation.save
puts new_consultation
puts new_consultation.date

Consultation.first.update(refund: 'none')
puts Consultation.first
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`new_consultation.save` checks to see if your object is valid before saving. If the object is valid, it will save and return `true`; otherwise, it will not save and return `false.

It looks like your object is invalid because you've specified:

```
property :refund, Text, required: true
```

If refund is required, you need to specify it or your object won't save.

Note that `puts new_consultation.date` works because `date` is still stored in the local object, even when `save` fails and none of the data is saved to the database.

Comment: Thanks @eiko for your answer. Actually I don't want `refund` to be required. but I try to remove `required: true` and I get this error : "NOT NULL constraint failed: consultations.refund (DataObjects::IntegrityError)". Just to test I try to let `refund` attributes to `require: true` and set it  (`new_consultation.refund = "no" `), and then you're write because it's working! But I can I remove the `require: true` without having this error, do you know how can I fix that ?

Comment: @Orsay could you try specifically putting `require: false` to see if that works?

Comment: If I put `require : false `and still setting it (`consultation.refund = 'no refund')`  it works. But if I don't set it I get `NOT NULL constraint failed: consultations.refund (DataObjects::IntegrityError)`